# Expire cookie files

Tags: php, session, cookies, logout

My website is behaving the way I want it to... I have to run my logout script twice before I'm completely signed out.

From what I can tell (from doing `get_defined_vars()` and printing the result) The first time i run the script it destroys the session, but doesn't expire the cookies. Here is my logout.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
// Set Session data to an empty array
$_SESSION = array();
// Expire their cookie files
if(isset($_COOKIE["id"]) && isset($_COOKIE["user"]) && isset($_COOKIE["pass"])) {
    setcookie("id", '', strtotime( '-50 days' ), '/');
    setcookie("user", '', strtotime( '-50 days' ), '/');
    setcookie("pass", '', strtotime( '-50 days' ), '/');
}
// Destroy the session variables
session_destroy();
// Double check to see if their sessions exists
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
header("location: message.php?msg=Error:_Logout_Failed");
} else {
    header("location: http://www.kokarma.com");
    exit();
} 
?>
```

What is wrong with my script?

Comment: You are storing the user id, name and password in a cookie?! Please don't do that.

Comment: Password is encrypted and hashed with bcrypt but I will remove that info from cookies. Only thing is I then only have user ID to use to compare to the database and retrieve the rest of the user vars on, I think that will be much more open?

Comment: That's why you use only a session. There's no need for storing any actual data in a cookie. All actual data is stored server-side, the client only gets a meaningless session id.

Comment: @deceze But the session is only good as long as the browser is open isn't it?

Comment: No, it's valid for as long as you make the session and cookie valid.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965569/session-cookies-cookies/4965588#4965588

Comment: Then I haven't understood (or I've forgot) something from reading up on sessions and cookies. Back to the drawing board it is...

Comment: Even if you need to set "custom" cookies because sessions don't serve you well for long time cookies (which is a perfectly valid concern), store an *opaque, pseudorandom nonsense token* somewhere (i.e. the database) and set it in the cookie. Never ever store any actual data in cookies for login purposes.

Comment: Thank you for your concern. will have to rewrite a fair bit of script throughout my app. I am going to include a "remember me" function so this is why I was looking to use cookies but you've pointed me in the right direction :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   setcookie("id", '',time()-100);
    setcookie("user", '',time()-100);
    setcookie("pass", '', time()-100);
```

Try this.

Comment: Thanks but didn't work. Is there maybe a way to just delete the cookie files?

Comment: Are you getting an error? or simply the cookie isn't expires?

Comment: I'm not getting the "logout failed" error I set but the `header(location` isn't running

Comment: So the problem isn't with the cookies. try set echo "error1/2", see what you're getting. also try change the if isset($_SESSION['username'] to if (!empty($_SESSION['username'])) and the session_destroy() to $_SESSION['username'] = '';

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you for your help! I didn't try the `set echo "error1/2";` Can you please explain what that is?

Comment: It's nothing. just to understand if the if is executed. but if it works now the problem was the session.